# Odata facilities in Power BI

Tags: odata, metadata, powerbi

I imported the Odata model from Northwind into power bi. Power Bi seems to understand the model and relationships in the Query editor. However, when it comes to create reports and visualisations it cannot understand the model and use columns to connect tables instead of metadata.

Is there a way to change how Power Bi create relationships between tables? Using odata metadata and not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the Relationship definitions manually, to repoint them at the correct columns.  From the Relationships pane, you can double-click on each relationship line to edit it, then choose the correct columns.